# returning a LineString on selecting its midpoint

Tags: python, point, shapely, linestring

I have a  list of shapely LineString,

```
[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x000001614D750CC0>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x000001614D750D68>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x000001614D750D30>]
```

and List of point geometry which are the mid-points of the Linestrings;

```
[<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000001614DC0D518>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000001614DC0D4E0>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000001614DCF9CC0>]
```

How to return Linestring on selecting its midpoint from the second list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your linestring are not crossing each other on the mid points you can simply use `intersects` method from shapely

```
for line in lines:
     for point in points:
          if line.intersects(point):
                # you have a match
```

if the do intersect you can get first the mid points from the linestrings using shapely's method `interpolate`

```
mid_point = line.interpolate(0.5, normalized = True)
```

then you use `intersects` , note that these methods require that your points are exactly the mid points of your lines, if you're not sure about it you can use a buffer with a tolerance distance ( also available in shapely )

Comment: I created midpoints of each LineString using `interpolate` so these midpoints must be within the lineStrings, but  `intersects` returns `False`.. though in Qgis midpoints are exactly on the line.. What could be possible wrong here?

Comment: @FJ_Abbasi have you tried the buffer ? `if line.intersects(point.buffer(some_value))`